# Kotlin Coroutines - Different options for using Coroutine Scope/Context?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to Kotlin/Coroutines and I've noticed two different ways to use `CoroutineScope`.

Option 1 is as follows, within any function:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch { 
    expensiveOperation() 
}
```

Option 2 is by implementing the `CoroutineScope` interface in your class, overriding the `CoroutineContext`, and then you can just launch coroutines easily with `launch` or `async`:

```
@Service
class ServiceImpl() : CoroutineScope {

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Default + Job()

    fun someFunction() {
        launch {
            expensiveOperation()
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently developing a backend endpoint that will do the following:

1. take a request
2. save the request context to a database
3. launch a non blocking coroutine in the background to perform an expensive/lengthy operation on the request, and immediately return an http 200. (essentially, once we have the context saved, we can return a response and let the request process in the background)

What is the difference in the two use cases, and for this scenario, which is the preferred method for obtaining a `CoroutineScope`?

This endpoint may receive multiple requests per second, and the lengthy operation will take a minute or two, so there will definitely be multiple requests processing at the same time, originating from various requests.

Also, if it's option 2, do I want to pass the scope/context to the function that does the heavy processing? Or is that unnecessary? For example:

class ServiceImpl() : CoroutineScope {

```
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = Dispatchers.Default + Job()

fun someFunction() {
    launch {
        expensiveOperation(CoroutineScope(coroutineContext))
    }
}

private fun expensiveOperation(scope: CoroutineScope) 
    {
        // perform expensive operation
    }
```

}

This is a Spring Boot app, and I'm using version `1.3` of `Kotlin`.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts/suggestions on how to best structure this service class. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend option 2. It will give you chance to clearly define parent `Job` for all of your coroutines. That gives a chance to shut down the whole execution correctly too.

There are several more coroutine context keys to include - `CoroutineName`, `CoroutineExceptionHandler` and so one.

Lastly, the structural concurrency may work better if you pass the `CoroutineScope` and the associated Job explicitly.
https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952

Also, take a look the explanation on that from Roman:
https://medium.com/@elizarov/coroutine-context-and-scope-c8b255d59055

Comment: Thank you - I'm starting to understand it a little better, but I can't say I fully grasp everything at this point. One other question that might help - if I have multiple requests processing at the same time, and one of them fails which would ends up being fatal to the CoroutineScope, are others in process insulated by any fallout from that failure? Or would they all be affected and die? Should I setup this class as a `prototype` bean, so when the controller forwards the request, each one is handled by independent objects that create individual CoroutineScopes?