# Springboot coroutine bean scope or local scope

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I have a requirement, where we want to asynchronously handle some upstream request/payload via coroutine. I see that there are several ways to do this, but wondering which is the right approach -

1. Provide explicit spring service class that implements CoroutineScope
2. Autowire singleton scope-context backed by certain defined thread-pool dispatcher.
3. Define method local `CoroutineScope` object

Following on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55174642/kotlin-coroutines-different-options-for-using-coroutine-scope-context), I'm wondering whats the trade-off if we define method local scopes like below -

```
fun testSuspensions(count: Int) {
  val launchTime = measureTimeMillis {
    val parentJob = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
      repeat(count) {
        this.launch {
          process()  //Some lone running process
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternative approach to `autowire` explicit scope object backed by custom dispatcher -

```
@KafkaListener(
    topics = ["test_topic"],
    concurrency = "1",
    containerFactory = "someListenerContainerConfig"
  )
  private fun testKafkaListener(consumerRecord: ConsumerRecord<String, ByteArray>, ack: Acknowledgment) {
    try {
      this.coroutineScope.launch {
        consumeRecordAsync(consumerRecord)
      }
    } finally {
      ack.acknowledge()
    }
  }

  suspend fun consumeRecordAsync(record: ConsumerRecord<String, ByteArray>) {
    println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Starting to consume record - ${record.key()}")
    val statusCode = initiateIO(record) // Add error-handling depending on kafka topic commit semantics.

    // Chain any-other business logic (depending on status-code) as suspending functions.
    consumeStatusCode(record.key(), statusCode)
  }

  suspend fun initiateIO(record: ConsumerRecord<String, ByteArray>): Int {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {  // Switch context to IO thread for http.
      println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] Executing network call - ${record.key()}")
      delay(1000 * 2) // Simulate IO call
      200 // Return status-code
    }
  }

  suspend fun consumeStatusCode(recordKey: String, statusCode: Int) {
    delay(1000 * 1) // Simulate work.
    println("[${Thread.currentThread().name}] consumed record - $recordKey, status-code - $statusCode")
  }
```

Autowiring bean as follows in some upstream config class -

```
@Bean(name = ["testScope"])
  fun defineExtensionScope(): CoroutineScope {
    val threadCount: Int = 4
    return CoroutineScope(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount).asCoroutineDispatcher())
  }
```

Comment: This is orthogonal to the question, but shouldn't the Kafka acknowledgement be done once the message has been processed (not just when it has been received)?

Comment: Well, that depends on how you want to process the kafka topic records - synchronous or asynchronous and how you handle errors/commits. On our case, we just forward the record to a DLQ and computation is asynchronous via coroutines. So, this makes me wonder how `scope` should be attached in first place.

Comment: Yes, but here it's acknowledged before even sending it to the queue. If the server dies before the coroutine executes, you'll lose this message

Comment: @Joffrey I've added comments to your answer. So, going back to the original post, is auto-wiring some coroutine-scope object (backed by an executor) recommended over global or method local scopes ? I've included code snippet where we define the bean.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your goal is. If you just want to avoid the thread-per-request model, you can use Spring's support for `suspend` functions in controllers instead (by using webflux), and that removes the need from even using an external scope at all:

```kotlin
suspend fun testSuspensions(count: Int) {
  val execTime = measureTimeMillis {
    coroutineScope {
      repeat(count) {
        launch {
          process()  // some long running process
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // all child coroutines are done at this point
}
```

If you really want your method to return immediately and schedule coroutines that outlive it, you indeed need that extra scope.

Regarding option 1), making custom classes implement `CoroutineScope` is not encouraged anymore (as far as I understood). It's usually suggested to use composition instead (declare a scope as a property instead of implementing the interface by your own classes). So I would suggest your option 2.

I would say option 3) is out of the question, because there is no point in using `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { ... }`. It's no better than using `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { ... }` (it has the same pitfalls) - you can read about the pitfalls of `GlobalScope` in [its documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/).

The main problem being that you run your coroutines outside structured concurrency (your running coroutines are not children of a parent job and may accumulate and hold resources if they are not well behaved and you forget about them). In general it's better to define a scope that is cancelled when you no longer need any of the coroutines that are run by it, so you can clean rogue coroutines.

That said, in some circumstances you do need to run coroutines "forever" (for the whole life of your application). In that case it's ok to use `GlobalScope`, or a custom application-wide scope if you need to customize things like the thread pool or exception handler. But in any case don't create a scope on the spot just to launch a coroutine without keeping a handle to it.

In your case, it seems you have no clear moment when you wouldn't care about the long running coroutines anymore, so you may be ok with the fact that your coroutines can live forever and are never cancelled. In that case, I would suggest a custom application-wide scope that you would wire in your components.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Joffrey. I now understand that there ain't much difference between creating method-local scope and `GlobalScope`. As, you said my use-case really doesn't care about having clear parent-child relationship as all that I'm interested in is asynchronous fire-and-forget workflow. If needed we can build error-handling into the code/function thats run as a coroutine. Lets say we auto-wire a scope object (some singleton component or service), don't we obscure the paren-child relationship as this scope can be used as parent for many-many child jobs ?

Comment: I've updated original question to include code that uses alternative approach - where we autowire some custom application scope. As you see from the code, all that we do is run some fire-and-forget logic. Since, the autowired-scope is bound to a singleton config and dependent service class (kafka-listener), it kinda obscures the parent-child relationship as we don't have any cancel based cleanups. Here, we will be creating many-many child coroutines and we are not holding any `job` references? So, does the implementation make sense or can we make any improvements ?